# Normalize Fasttext word embedding vector generated by model

Tags: python, tensorflow, normalization, word-embedding, fasttext

I'm currently using FastText to get the word embeddings for some input text data in order to catch similarity among them and give those embedding as input to a neural network for a NER task.
I've first tried to use the fastText .vec file and I was able to get good similarity result from them, then I've tried to use the .bin model file so that I can get embeddings also from out-of-vocabulary terms but I've noticed that the vectors generated from the .vec and the .bin file are different.
The .vec file contains embeddings clipped to a range of [-1,1] while this is not true for the embedding contained in the .bin file.
Using the .bin file I get very bad results so I'm trying to undestand if this is due to the fact the these vectors (.bin) are not normalized.

Is there a good way to normalize these vectors in a range [-1, 1] using Python?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Just re-scale the data into range [-1, 1]. Wish it may help.

```
def norm(data):
    min_v, max_v = min(data), max(data)
    mid_v = (max_v + min_v) >> 1
    len_v = float((max_v - min_v) >> 1)
    return [(v-mid_v)/len_v for v in data]
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for your reply. I'm getting an error since I'm working with float values and the ">>" operand is applied on an integer value.
My problem now is that the embeddings values are really small and I think that this is why I'm getting bad results, while using the .vec file the values are quite "normal" and the results are good

Comment: @jesper If the data is float, you can change the code into `mid_v = (max_v+min_v)/2.0`，">>" is more efficient when dealing with integers.

Comment: @jesper I am not family with word-embedding stuff, but as for your problem, I think if the input data is very small(all near zero), it will affect the performance of neural network. So as you have mentioned, some kind of normalization method is needed to scale up your data. My suggestion is that you can search normalization from tensorflow's documentation, it will be much better than your self-implemented algorithm. Also check the documentation of the input .bin model, it may have some references about how to deal with the data.

Comment: thanks, I will mark yours as the accepted answer since it could be a good solution for general pourpose. I will definetly add a specific solution as soon I will find one.